# Vertica query to get difference between two group by result

Tags: sql, vertica

Having following data

```
+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
| firstgroupId    | firstCount  |  firstId | secondclusterId | secondCount | secondId |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
| 100001          | 3           | 3000001  | 100003          | 4           | 3000001  |
| 100001          | 3           | 3000002  | 100003          | 4           | 3000002  |
| 100001          | 3           | 3000003  | 100003          | 4           | 3000003  |
| 100002          | 2           | 3000004  | 100003          | 4           | 3000004  |
| 100002          | 2           | 3000005  | 100002          | 4           | 3000005  |
| 100003          | 3           | 3000006  | 100002          | 4           | 3000006  |
| 100003          | 3           | 3000007  | 100002          | 4           | 3000007  |
| 100003          | 3           | 3000008  | 100002          | 4           | 3000008  |
| 100004          | 2           | 3000009  | 100005          | 2           | 3000009  |
| 100004          | 2           | 3000010  | 100005          | 2           | 3000010  |
+-----------------+-------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
```

here we can see

- for firstId 3000001,3000002,3000003 are grouped together but  secondId 3000001,3000002,3000003,3000004 are grouped together Here I need result as 3000004 as this is odd man out
- same for 3000005 : 3000005 and 3000004 are joined together in firstPart but not in second part

need to find out odd man out by comparing two groups Id ?

Comment: What do you mean they are grouped together ? you mean based on `firstCount` ?

Comment: @Sam . . . I think the overlap is based on `firstgroupId` and `secondclusterId`.  This is an interesting question, but not very well phrased.

Comment: What do you mean firstId is grouped together? What do you mean by "result as 3000004 as this is odd man out"?

Comment: Let me explain more over this 
1) firstGroupId     100001 -> 3000001|3000002|3000003 (these 3 are grouped together)
   secondclusterId  100003 -> 3000001|3000002|3000003|3000004 (these 4 are grouped together)
   Trying to identify id which is present i one group but not in other group
2) In this scenario
   firstGroupId 100002 -> 3000004|3000005
   for secondClusterId ->  3000004 belongs to 100003 , 3000005 belongs to 100002
as output tried to achieve 
output
-------
3000004
3000005

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want the ids where the overlap between the group and cluster is not the "largest" overlap.  If I so, I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by firstgroupId order by overlap_count desc) as overlap_rank
      from (select t.*,
                   count(*) over (partition by firstgroupId, secondclusterId) as overlap_count
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where overlap_rank > 1;
```

If you know you are looking for singleton outliers, you can use just the innermost subquery and use `where overlap_count = 1`.

Comment: hey thanks gordon .. Just twisted this query little bit and got my result